# How to link script file in footer.ejs?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I want to link script.js to my project.
I write folowing code on

**footer.ejs:**

```
<script src="../static/js/script.js"></script>
```

But I got error:

> Cannot GET /static/js/script.js

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to a path typo somewhere.

For example, if in your app.js you use `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static/'));` Then in your script tag you would need to use `<script src="js/script.js">`

If you changed your app.js to `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));`

Then you would need to use `<script src="/js/script.js"></script>`

Check everywhere that you reference that file and make sure you have the correct filepath.